# VBA Word Pull the "copies" variable when printing

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

I was wondering if it's possible to access the "Copies" variable when printing?

I want to insert "Print x of y" on the footer of each copy, where "y" is the "Copies" variable.

I therefore need to access the variable to iterate through a loop. Is this possible or do i have to find another solution?

I am using the BeforePrint event.

[image: Picture]

Thanks in advance
-Beats

(P.S. I've tried using dialogs with no success.)

Comment: Please show us the code you are using and clearly describe the problem you are having with the code.

Comment: You probably can't, but you can make your own "print x copies" macro which does the same. See https://superuser.com/questions/1329783/print-serial-number-or-incrementing-number-in-word-document-footer for some ideas.